# Efficient way of adding 6K urls into JSON class

Tags: ios, json, interpolation, textwrangler

I have approx 6k urls to put into a `.json` list in my iOS app

```
 [{
  "trigger": {
    "url-filter": "somepage1.com",
    "load-type" : ["third-party"]
  },
  "action": {
    "type": "doSoemthing"
  }
}, {
  "trigger": {
    "url-filter": "somepage2.com",
    "load-type" : ["third-party"]
  },
  "action": {
    "type": "doSoemthing"
  }
}, {
  "trigger": {
    "url-filter": "anotherpage.net",
    "load-type" : ["third-party"]
  },
  "action": {
    "type": "doSoemthing"
  }
}, {
  "trigger": {
    "url-filter": "yetanotherone.net", <---replace with another 6k 
    "load-type" : ["third-party"]
  },
  "action": {
    "type": "doSoemthing"
  }]

  ...etc
```

Im after an efficient way to automate this (efficient for entering data manually rather than cpu processing efficiency). Not having really done anything but very basic json before, i'm wondering if there is a way I can make an `array` in my `.json.class` and interpole all the urls?

Or

Perhaps using textwrangler.  I realise this wouldn't work in Text Wrangler "as is",  this is just to illustrate what I would like to achieve

[image]

The individual urls are in raw text format list

Comment: Do you have that url's in array ? What is the structure of that ? How did you get those ?

Comment: The urls at the moment are just raw data in a huge list in text wrangler

Comment: With **grep** enabled, you could have searched for `^(.+)$` and replaced with `, {\n  "trigger": {\n    "url-filter": "\1",\n    "load-type" : ["third-party"]\n  },\n  "action": {\n    "type": "doSoemthing"\n  }]`